# How can I Boolean based on whether my search string is a subset of the class?

Tags: wordpress, class, search, hide

I have a Wordpress site with a long table of people and data and I need to add a search filter which shows only the people who match the typed in words. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').keyup(function() { 
                var searchFilterVal = $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').val();
        searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.replace(/ /g, '-');
        searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.toLowerCase();

        if(searchFilterVal == '') {
            $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
        } else {

            $('tr.fellows').each(function() {

            if(!$(this).hasClass(searchFilterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hide');

                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
                }
            });
        }
});
});
```

This works great as long as the input exactly matches the class. I need `if(!$(this).hasClass(searchFilterVal)) {`

to basically say "If (this) .hasClass(if the input matches any portion of the class)"

Does that make sense? Here is the page:
http://cambridgefellows.com/directory-of-fellows/?searchFilterInput=Media

Is is the second search field - the one on the right hand side of the drop down menus.

I'm sorry if this question is not asked clearly - please let me know if I can make it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear, what do you want to achieve now .

Comment: Right now if I search for the word "Media" then the filter will hide everyone that does not have precisely "Media" as one of their chunks of data. But I'd like to be able to search for "Med" and have anyone who has "Media" or also "Medical" etc show up. I need the IF that looks for hasClass to accept a subset of the class.

Comment: Also - right now each <TR> of the table gets all of the data in all of the <TD>s of that row added as classes to the <TR> - that's how the filter works.

Comment: By which parameter it filter's the result,  currently. ?

Comment: Right now when you input a search string, it looks to see if any <TR>s have that search string as a class. Each <TR> has the content of every single <TD> added as a class. So if your search string input is exactly equal to some of the <TD> content, then the filter will show those <TR>s, and hide all others. But I need the filter to work so that the match doesn't have to be precise. So that a partial match will work as well. I thought possibly indexOf() would work, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: So what I'm trying to get is this: `if(the class contains (but doesn't necessarily match) the search string) {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .. I've cheked it , it's working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').keyup(function() { 
                var searchFilterVal = $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').val();
        searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.replace(/ /g, '-');
        searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.toLowerCase();

        if(searchFilterVal == '') {
            $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
        } else {

            $('tr.fellows').each(function() {
            var pattern = $(this).attr('class');    // the pattern to be matched 
            var match = pattern.match(searchFilterVal);//If pattern matches it returns the match

            if(!match) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hide');

                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
                }
            });
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: That definitely works! I had abandoned the need for classes (which came from the method I was using for the drop down menu filter) and had gotten it to work using .text() - but this solution is precisely what I was looking for. I was not familiar with .match() - thank you! Now I need to figure out how to get the two different filtering methods I'm using to work together, but that will be a different question. Thanks!